# CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed

Tags: extensions, magento-connect-manager

I tried to install "Delhivery_Lastmile-0.3.0 rar extension" through magento connect manager

but i got following error :

CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed.

Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel.

I am not familiar with ssh, is there any solution for this without using ssh commands.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did some googling and I'm afraid it's only possible via SSH.

From this source: http://help.granify.com/install/magento/troubleshooting-guide/

> CONNECT ERROR: The ‘community’ channel is not installed. Please use
>   the MAGE shell script to install the ‘community’ channel.
>
> The root cause of this is that Magento wasn’t completely setup when
>   installed. You’re most likely to encounter this when the Magento
>   installation is new or there haven’t been any extensions installed
>   yet.
>
> To fix this, have your system administrator SSH into your web server
>   and run the following commands:
>
> ```
> chmod 777 mage
> ./mage mage-setup
> ```

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I've just run across the same issue on a live site. Is there any chance that running this could affect the site?

Comment: @StevenJeffries I'm not sure, could be. I never work with connect myself

Comment: i am working on localhost and facing same problem what i have to do .